# Receiving Multiplied Rundown events instead of once for the same ETW session

Tags: c#, etw

I have a simple usage of ETW.

I've subscribed to receive events from USB4 provider.

I have 2 sessions:

- A real time session which I use to print to the console log
- Second for log the events to a log file for a further investigation.

  ```
    var s = new TraceEventSession("mySession", TraceEventSessionOptions.NoPerProcessorBuffering);
    var s2 = new TraceEventSession($"mySession-log", @"C:\mySession.etl", TraceEventSessionOptions.NoPerProcessorBuffering);

    var PROVIDER_GUID = new Guid("AE795D36-2B11-5EFB-C7E0-5D552BC55D6C");

    var dynamicTraceEventParser = s.Source.Dynamic;
    dynamicTraceEventParser.All += delegate (TraceEvent data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Received DRD event: {data.EventName}");
    };

    s.EnableProvider(PROVIDER_GUID);
    s2.EnableProvider(PROVIDER_GUID);


    s.Source.Process();
  ```

**Excepted Result:**

Receive the event RundownStart/Start only once in the log.

**Actual result:**

Receive the event RundownStart/Start twice in the log.

I've realized that creating only one session, I receive the event only once but I'm not sure how creating two different un depend sessions can cause this.

Are the sessions depend of each other?

Thank you :)